# How does ParseQuery.Include() actually work?

Tags: c#, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I have a pair of classes derived from ParseObject, DbRound, and DbLocation. DbRound has a field named "Location" that points to a DbLocation. I create a query and Include( "Location" ) hoping to get the referenced DbLocation when I fetch a DbRound; no joy. However, I can fetch the Location in a subsequent fetch operation.

My objective is to get both the DbRound and the referenced DbLocation in a single query. Am I misunderstanding the intent of ParseQuery.Include(), or using it incorrectly? Or am I going about this the wrong way altogether?

This runs in Unity. Here is the relevant code:

```
IEnumerator CheckRound( string roundId )
{
    // DbRound.Location is a pointer to DbLocation (a ParseObject derivative)
    var query = new ParseQuery< DbRound >();
    query.Include( "Location" );

    var task = query.GetAsync( roundId );

    while( !task.IsCompleted ) yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

    if( ! task.IsFaulted )
    {
        // task.Result.Location contains a default-constructed DbLocation
        Debug.Log( "task.Result.Location.IsDataAvailable: " + 
                    task.Result.Location.IsDataAvailable );

        var rel = new List< ParseObject > { task.Result.Location };
        var t = ParseObject.FetchAllIfNeededAsync( rel );
        while( ! t.IsCompleted ) yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        // now task.Result.Location has a value of the referenced DbLocation
        Debug.Log( "task.Result.Location.IsDataAvailable: " + 
                    task.Result.Location.IsDataAvailable );

        DisplayRound( task.Result );
    }
}
```

Log results:

```
12/28/2015 18:30:00.4214 task.Result.Location.IsDataAvailable: False
12/28/2015 18:30:10.7530 task.Result.Location.IsDataAvailable: True
```

TIA,
--Joshua

[EDIT: per request, adding source]

First, what drives the demo:

```
    IEnumerator SetUpBugDemo()
    {
        var location = new DbLocation( "A desolate place" );
        yield return StartCoroutine( Store( location ) );

        var round = new DbRound( location );
        yield return StartCoroutine( Store( round ) );

        yield return StartCoroutine( CheckRound( round.ObjectId ) );
    }

    IEnumerator Store( DbLocation location )
    {
        var task = location.SaveAsync();

        while( !task.IsCompleted ) { yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); }
    }

    IEnumerator Store( DbBogusRound round )
    {
        var task = round.SaveAsync();

        while( !task.IsCompleted ) { yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame(); }
    }
```

And now the derived ParseObject declarations:

```
[ParseClassName( "Location" )]
public class DbLocation : ParseObject
{
    [ParseFieldName( "Text" )]
    public string Text
    {
        get { return GetProperty< string >( "Text" ); }
        set { SetProperty< string >( value, "Text" ); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName( "HashTag" )]
    public string HashTag
    {
        get { return GetProperty< string >( "HashTag" ); }
        set { SetProperty< string >( value, "HashTag" ); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName( "BreakdownValue" )]
    public int BreakdownValue
    {
        get { return GetProperty< int >( "BreakdownValue" ); }
        set { SetProperty< int >( value, "BreakdownValue" ); }
    }

    [ParseFieldName( "CreationValue" )]
    public int CreationValue
    {
        get { return GetProperty< int >( "CreationValue" ); }
        set { SetProperty< int >( value, "CreationValue" ); }
    }

    public DbLocation( string text )
    {
        Text = text;
        HashTag = "<none>";
        BreakdownValue = 0;
        CreationValue = 0;
    }

    public DbLocation()
    { /* required for Parse */}
}

[ParseClassName( "Round" )]
public class DbRound : ParseObject
{
    [ParseFieldName( "Location" )]
    public DbLocation Location
    {
        get { return GetProperty< DbLocation >( "Location" ); }
        set
        {
            var locationRef = 
                ParseObject.CreateWithoutData<DbLocation>( value.ObjectId );
            SetProperty( locationRef, "Location" );
        }
    }

    public DbRound( DbLocation location )
    {
        Location = location;
    }

    public DbRound()
    { /* required for Parse */ }
}
```

[EDIT: Adding Parse API Console output]

There is one instance of Round and Location produced from the sample code above.

```
GET classes/Round
RESPONSE
{
    "results": [
        {
            "Location": {
                "__type": "Pointer",
                "className": "Location",
                "objectId": "YuJlyxhRSe"
            },
            "createdAt": "2015-12-29T22:53:59.966Z",
            "objectId": "ugg61jLPN6",
            "updatedAt": "2015-12-29T22:53:59.966Z"
        }
    ]
}


GET classes/Location
RESPONSE
{
    "results": [
        {
            "BreakdownValue": 0,
            "CreationValue": 0,
            "HashTag": "<none>",
            "Text": "A desolate place",
            "createdAt": "2015-12-29T22:53:59.319Z",
            "objectId": "YuJlyxhRSe",
            "updatedAt": "2015-12-29T22:53:59.319Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your expectation about include() is correct.  The query looks fine.  How are you proving "no joy" to yourself?  Post a case where the query gets a DbRound result along with log output that illustrates that the pointed-to Location object is not returned.

Comment: Okay, I edited the example to log the IsDataAvailable state. Further, I've been observing this stepping through the code in the debugger.

Comment: Could we look at the objects themselves?

Comment: I've added the derived ParseObject classes and the driver I'm using to demonstrate the phenomenon.

Comment: Sorry, I meant console output of the returned objects themselves.  I'm not convinced that you're not getting the included objects.

Comment: Ah, silly me. :) Console output added. It is consistent with values I observe in the debugger *after* the FetchAllIfNeededAsync() call.

Comment: Okay, to double check: that log output at the end of the OP is generated by the query at the top?  (Not by the rest api or something else?)  If so, I'm stumped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99263/discussion-between-jrl-and-danh).

Answer (score 1):

Heh, I figured out the issue. ParseQuery.Include() does not alter the query object; it creates a new instance that adds the Include(). So what I need is:

```
var query = new ParseQuery< DbRound >();
query = query.Include( "Location" );
```

And then the query returns the data for Location as expected.